# Expand grid cells but stop at contents of listBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF form with some text fields and two ListBoxes:

```xml
<TextBlock>Label</TextBlock>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Input}"/>
<TextBlock>List Label</TextBlock>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}"/>
<TextBlock>Second List Label</TextBlock>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}"/>
```

I'd like for the two ListBoxes to expand vertically to fit their container, but for each one to stop expanding once its scrollbar is no longer necessary. The closest I've come is with a grid:

```xml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">

  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="40" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="40" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
    <TextBlock>Label</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Input}"/>
    <TextBlock>List Label</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}"/>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">Second List Label</TextBlock>
  <ListBox Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}"/>
</Grid>
```

However, then the space taken up by the list boxes is always the same due to the asterisk row height, so if one list stops growing, the remainder of the height to match the other list is left as empty space at the bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a DockPanel...

```
<DockPanel >
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Label</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Input}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">List Label</TextBlock>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinHeight="40" MaxHeight="200"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top">Second List Label</TextBlock>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}" MinHeight="40"/>
</DockPanel>
```

This fulfills all of your requirement.  The container is completely filled.  The listboxes stop expanding when scrollbars are no longer needed. However if there are too many items in the 1st listbox the 2nd one will disappear completely.  This is why I put in a max height for the first list box.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried this, but the ListBoxes just expanded to their full height, regardless of the size of the DockPanel.

Comment: The DockPanel will constraint the listboxes...it cannot be otherwise.  To prove this to yourself add Height="300" to the DockPanel.  You will now see a scroll bar on the bottom listbox.  You need to put the DockPanel inside an element that will constraint it, for example a window.